# Prevent an exception when I cancel an openfiledialog?

Tags: c#

I am having a problem when I click cancel on an openfiledialog in c#, it throws an exception. This is my code:

I tried to look at some other Stackoverflow solutions but none of them work. Here is a example:

```
private void BtnCargarImagen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //OFD = openfiledialog
            OFD.ShowDialog();
            PicFotografia.Image = Image.FromFile(OFD.FileName);
            MessageBox.Show("LA IMAGAN HA SIDO CARGADA");
            DialogResult result;
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                return OFD.FileName;
            }

            return null;
```

When the "if" part is placed on the code, it marks error on both "returns".

Without the dialog result part from top to bottom when I click on cancel, it marks an exception.

```
private void BtnCargarImagen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //OFD = openfiledialog
                OFD.ShowDialog();
                PicFotografia.Image = Image.FromFile(OFD.FileName);
                MessageBox.Show("LA IMAGAN HA SIDO CARGADA");
            }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your method is `void` that's why you can't return, but that's probably not the only problem. What is the exception?

Comment: How are you setting the result. I see a declaration and then use. There is no assignment to result variable.

Comment: DialogResult result = OFD.ShowDialog();

Comment: Please, tell us what you want to achieve and the error message you receive when trying one or the other solution. Most probably you should just read the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-open-files-using-the-openfiledialog-component and follow the example provided there.

Comment: Yeah you can't return anything from a void function but the compiler should be complaining about this. OP - "An exception" tells us absolutely nothing about your problem. There are many, many types of exceptions and they all indicate different things. Update your question with information we can actually use to help you with.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few reasons you are getting an exception.

The code below should give you a `CS0165` error code meaning: `Use of unassigned local variable 'result'`

```
 if (result == DialogResult.OK)
```

To fix this error, you need to assign it something. For example: `DialogResult result = DialogResult.OK;`

Second issue I see is you should get a `CS0127` error code meaning: `BtnCargarImagen_Click returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression`

To fix this error you need to remove the `return` statements because you are *not* returning anything since it's a method/void and not a function.

Here's what I would do *going off your current code*...

```
private static string GetFileName()
{
   using (OpenFileDialog OFD = new OpenFileDialog())
   {
      if (OFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      {
         return OFD.FileName;
      }
      else { return null; }
   }
}
```

Here you can return a string if user did select a `file` inside the `OpenFileDialog`, then you can use this in your other method to determine what you need to do...

```
 private void BtnCargarImagen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    string fileName = GetFileName();
    if(fileName != null)
    {
       // You may want to use PicFotografia.BackgroundImage here.
       PicFotografia.Image = Image.FromFile(fileName);
       MessageBox.Show("LA IMAGAN HA SIDO CARGADA");
    }
 }
```

On another note, I would look into [FileDialog.Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter?view=netframework-4.8) as if you pick something other than an image, it will throw an exception...